# Email sql query results of multiple email addresses daily

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, email

I am fairly green at SQL and have reached a road block. I have a Job that already runs a query and sends an email to our purchasing department agents via the agent.

Here is my sample data they receive as a text attachment:

```
po_num  vend_num    qty_needed  external_email_addr
318     1           200         email@earthlink.net
318     1           910         email@earthlink.net
703     2           250         email@row.com
993     3           3600        email@cast.com
993     3           3600        email@cast.com
676     4           1           NULL
884     5           10000       email@Futures.com
118     5           2500        email@Futures.com
```

My goal is to automatically send each vendor one email of the qty_needed using the email address in external_email_addr field. Also, if the email address is NULL it would send me an email that this needs to be fixed.

I am not sure how complicated or simple this is but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it should also include the po_num to the vendor as well.

Comment: This is one of the rare times where a loop is the best (and only) option. Loop through the results of your query and send an email with the details you want to send. And in your loop if the email is null....well....send a different email to a known address.

Comment: @SeanLange nope you can get away with a COALESCE statement.

Comment: @SeanLange then use a CASE statement.

Comment: @Namphibian well sure COALESCE would work but you still have to use a loop to send different emails.

Comment: I can't comment on the sending as there is very little detail on it. The edited version of query will eliminate null and blank values.

Comment: Agreed. Either version of your query would likely retrieve the right values from the table. But then you have to loop them.

Answer (score 0):

Since the po_num is unique you will generate several mails per email address per day based on the example data you provided.

I dont have access to SQL at the moment so the syntax might need some sprucing up.

```
SELECT po_num,
       vend_num,
       qty_needed,
       CASE WHEN external_email_addr ='' THEN COALESCE(external_email_addr,'defaultempty@fixthisproblem.com') ELSE external_email_ddr END AS email_address
FROM table_name
```

Comment: @SeanLange  has the right idea(some kinda of loop). I would like to send one email that would contain all results instead of sending individual emails one row of data at a time.  The data could return 3 - 8 different POs to the same vendor on that day and I would want to send 3-8 separate emails to that person...but one email with all the rows of data. I hope I am not asking for a lot....